# Adobe Illustrator: A transparent background for an character of a file pdf

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, background

**First question:** I'm starting to use Adobe Illustrator recently. I would like to know what are the commands to convert the white background of a pdf into one that is transparent background.

**Second question:** I use, now, Adobe Illustrator CC, relase 2015, tryout. Thanks an help of an user and various comments I have to find the “trasparent grid”, of my file .pdf, in the position of the figure shown here:

[image]

Here there is the path of the “trasparent grid”:

> Visualizza>Mostra griglia di trasparenza

instead of

> View>show>trasparent grid

Probabily the user has a different version of mine. Now I have another problem. How I do to remove the withe background and to have only the black character “P”?

[image]

I do not like the white background and I would remove it. Could someone explain to me step by step what I must do to make the background transparent and just leave the character?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator uses a transparent background by default.
If you open an illustrator document or a illustrator-made PDF in Photoshop, you'll see that the background is transparent.
Illustrator simulates the white background.
If you want to work without it, choose View > Show Transparency Grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Why I have a negative score for my question? I have voted often positive.

Comment: @Sebastiano someone may not like your question for some reason.  We request people to leave a comment why they downvoted but some do not.  If you did find Vinny's answer to answer your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I know the procedure: I hope that you vote positive my question. If someone needs a simple help, what sense does it have to vote negatively? A clear and well-made question?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Excuse me for this comment. But is it possible that many times I had have downvotes? Thank you very much and excuse me for my disturb.

Answer (score 2):

That does not appear to be a character, as selected text will show a baseline in Illustrator. It looks like it might be a raster image (or perhaps a tracing) given the lack of paths in the selection, but hard to be sure.

Here's what the 3 items look like selected on the artboard:

[image]

A better way to see what type of item you're working with is in the Layers Palette:

[image]

If it is an image, you could do this:

Create a duplicate of the image (Ctrl+C, then Ctrl+F). Select both. Make Mask through the Transparency palette. Invert Mask. Here's how that should look:
[image]

If it's a tracing:
Use the menu item Object>Expand and make sure Object & Fill are selected in the dialog.

[image]

Then fly out the group it made in the Layers palette, pull out the black paths and delete the white paths.

[image]

Comment: I did not understand very much what I have to do exactly I have the version AI CC 2015 realase. You could add screenshots please to explain step by step what I have to do. Thank you so much and of course positive vote your answer. Is the question I asked clear?

Comment: Thanks for the vote. I've added screenshots. Hopefully that helps. But if not, feel free to ask specific questions about any particular step.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "File" menu and choose "Export" option from the drop-down menu.

In the appeared window, select the PNG file format.

Rename it and press the "Save" button.

In the following window, set the "Transparent" PNG option in the "Background Color" drop-down menu.

Then press the "OK" button. Now your Illustrator file has been successfully saved with a transparent background.